# Friend(ly) versus funn(y). -Ly versus -y for adjectives

Tags: historical-linguistics

Is there a solid historical reason for some adjectives from nouns taking -y as an ending and some taking -ly?

Fun => funny (*funnly)
Friend => friendly (*friendy)

Comment: @Review The question asks for diachronic (or maybe also synchronic) explanations for a paticular morphological pattern, not about usage, so I wouldn't regard the question as off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

The explanation is rather simple. 
The suffix [*-ly (2)*](http://www.etymonline.com/word/-ly) is derived from the Proto-Germanic suffix **-līkaz* originally with the sense of 'having the body or form of',  related to the Proto-Germanic noun **līką* 'body'. It is a cognate of the English *like*. So, *friendly* can be interpreted as 'friend-like' and, say, *masterly* as 'master-like.'

The suffix [*-y (2)*](http://www.etymonline.com/word/-y) means "full of or characterized by," that is why *funny* can be interpreted as 'full of fun / characterized by fun' and *dirty* as 'full of dirt / characterized by dirt.'

This is the main guideline for the usage of the two suffixes. Naturally, there are exceptions and inconcistencies in their usage caused by historical reasons, but the main trend is like this.